# What is the new interview procedure added for people flying to USA?

Tags: usa, india, airport-security

There is recent news that there is an interview process added for people coming to the USA from other countries.

I am a student studying in the USA. I am going to India in December for vacation and coming back in January. When I come back, what should I expect?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These questions are **not** extra "customs and immigration" interviews when you get to the US. They are extra questions by the airline **before** you board your flight to the US, and they apply to everyone coming to the US regardless of their citizenship.

There seems to be some confusion around whether everyone needs to be interviewed and exactly what they're asked. Here are articles from [a Canadian TV Network](http://www.ctvnews.ca/business/new-questions-and-searches-greet-travellers-flying-to-the-u-s-1.3651802), and [Time USA](http://time.com/4998298/new-security-screenings-begin-for-passengers-on-u-s-bound-flights/).

They don't seem super onerous: did you pack your bags yourself, are you carrying anything for someone else, that sort of thing. But it seems to vary around the world in these first few days of the new setup.

Comment: I experienced this kind of interview in June 2015 when flying Delta from Zurich to New York, so not something new

Comment: I experienced this kind of interview already 15 years ago when flying to the USA from Argentina, so I'm surprised this is news.

Comment: @Crazydre Until recently only the US carriers did this. If you purchased your ticket on Air France or Swiss you would not have had an interview.

Comment: @Calchas The interview, of course, was not conducted by Americans, but local, German-speaking Swissport employees

Comment: @Crazydre Perhaps you were selected for some kind of additional screening? Or maybe it's just the scope of this that changed (applying it to everyone?)

Comment: @reirab No, everyone had to go through it, a few metres to the side of the gate, to have their boarding pass stamped

Comment: @Coke Interesting. I don't recall running into anything like that when flying to the U.S. from Asia or Canada. Seems like FCO might have had something set up before even getting to the check-in desk, though, now that you mention it. Nothing at the gate area there, though.

Comment: I was questioned like this in 2002 in Amsterdam before flying to Boston.

Comment: I am wondering about the effect of those questions (beside politics)? Would any terrorist be dumb enough to say he didn’t pack his bags, but his explosives expert did that for him?? Seriously?

Comment: Looks like after many years,  the Israelis gave them the secret anti-hijacking recipe.

Comment: @Aganju the goal isn't to catch terrorists, in Israel (where they've been asking these questions for ages and I've been asked them at least a hundred times for 25 years) they actually explain why they're asking them immediately after they do: "We're asking you these questions since there have been cases where things have been planted in peoples' bags, or people have been asked to bring seemingly innocent gifts to friends who ended up being bombs" (they have a more diplomatic, Hebrew way of saying that, and you're asked regardless of being a citizen).

Comment: "Did you pack your bags yourself" and "are you carrying anything for anyone else" are stock questions domestic in-USA travelers get asked by TSA, and have since 2001. It's part to educate "don't let strangers mess with your bags"...  and if there is contraband, to snare you and deny you any "I didn't know that was there" defense.

Comment: @reirab To clarify this is the standard procedure for all Delta departures from Zurich

Comment: @Harper I haven't been asked that question for domestic travel in the USA for many years.

Comment: I remember being asked that question back in 1989. after Lockerbie. So that's 28 years already.

Answer (score 6):

The questions asked of travelers coming to the United States are not new. These questions began appearing to help curtail plane hijackings and smugglings that were happening in the 60s, 70s, 80s, etc. I've been asked  questions about who packed my bags, did I visit a farm, how long was I gone, where did I stay, and where will I stay in the U.S., etc. for decades whenever going back and forth to Canada. I remember the first time I heard them when returning from Europe (London) was in 1990. (The questions in London included asking if I was carrying any batteries. I said No but when I got on the plane I realized I was wearing a battery in my watch, my camera had a battery, and my toothbrush had a battery. I have to assume they knew most people don't think about what uses a battery.) For some sample questions asked of persons entering the U.S. see https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/entering-us-what-expect-airport-29797.html. This is a good explanation page.

It is a good idea to look through the U.S. Customs and Border Protection website and specifically at "Know Before You Go" information. See https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/know-before-you-go so you are prepared before leaving with the proper documentation for returning with personal used items that may normally require duty and for what items can be brought back or not brought back from your travels.

Since you are a student, you should know the following information at "What travel documents and identification are required for a foreign national to enter the U.S.?" (https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/572/kw/students). "Continuing students who are going to travel outside of the United States must see their foreign student advisor and obtain an endorsement from the DSO or RO. The endorsement will be made on page 3 of the SEVIS Form I-20 or page 1 of the DS-2019. When returning to the United States, a continuing student/exchange visitor must present a valid SEVIS Form I-20 or DS-2019 with the DSO or RO signature showing that the student is active and in good standing with the school or program." For more information, see the "Student and Exchange Visitor Program" at https://www.ice.gov/sevis.

Have a great visit and a safe journey.

Comment: The farm question has nothing to do with hijacking.

Comment: I didn't say it did. It is an example of one of several kinds of questions asked when entering the country. They are testing your response time and judging your honesty. When crossing the border by car once I was asked if I was bringing in a kitchen sink. I had the back of the car filled with things for the cottage. I asked why the question about the kitchen sink and he said many Americans bring a replacement sink for their cottage. The answer is the questions aren't a new process. They've been around for some time, weren't always asked, but became more prevalent after several travel incidents

Comment: Yes, but the questions you describe are asked **on arrival** by US customs and immigration. this question is about questions asked **before departure** by airline staff. There is a difference. Your last paragraph is very interesting for the OP; good work there.